# Ajax call problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having problems returning the HTML from this ajax call. It works fine in FF but gives me a "null" in IE for the `alert(result.html());`

Here is the code. Any ideas? Thanks!!!

The errors variable is also null in IE.

Also, it makes not difference what element i use in the `.find()` as it still comes up null.

```
function update_price() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $("form[name='MainForm']").attr('action'),
        data: $("form[name='MainForm']").serialize() + '&btnupdateprice.x=0&btnupdateprice.y=0',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            var errors = $(response).find("#listOfErrorsSpan");
            var result = $(response).find(".colors_productprice:eq(0)");
            alert(result.html());
            $(".colors_productprice:eq(0)").replaceWith('<font class="colors_productprice">' + result.html() + '</font>');
            $('#listOfErrorsSpan').replaceWith('<span id="listOfErrorsSpan">' + errors.html() + '</span>');
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    $("select[name^='SELECT___'],input[name^='SELECT___'][type='radio']").each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            update_price();
        });
    });
    $("a[href^='javascript:change_option']").each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            var result_href = $(this).attr('href').match(/\'(.*?)\'/)[1];
            var result_val = $(this).attr('href').match(/\,(.*?)\)/)[1];
            change_option(result_href, result_val);
            update_price();
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML from the Ajax call.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<b><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice"><span class="price_name"><font class="text colors_text"><b>Our Price: </b></font></span>
<span class="price1">$505.00</span>
</font>
</b>
</tr>
</table>
```

In FF I get this for the alert.

```
<span class="price_name"> Price with added options: </span><span class="price1">$505.00</span>
```

Comment: You want someone to debug your work with guessing what your HTML is like.  Why don't you post the example in jsFiddle or something useful?  Why don't you describe what version of IE you're using?

Comment: IE8, I have updated the question with the HTML snippet from the Ajax call

Answer (score 0):

you might have errors on this code

```
var errors=$(response).find("#listOfErrorsSpan");
```

var result=$(response).find(".colors_productprice:eq(0)");
alert(result.html());

i am not sure maybe the selector for $(response) is undefined

Comment: I don't think so as there are no javascript errors being generated and works fine in FF. Just can't figure out why? Perhaps this is the wrong method to get the response. Removing that line has the same effect in IE.

Answer (score 0):

The :eq(0) in your find statement may be the problem. It is probably sufficient to just say find(".colors_productprice").

Comment: Its not the only element with class="colors_productprice" as I only showed the relevant HTML. Thx though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `</td>`

Not sure this is the root problem, but FF and IE work differently in quirksmode, especially when inserting elements into the DOM on the fly.